# make one array the key and another array the value

Tags: php, arrays

Say I have 2 arrays, the first array is:

```
Array (
    [3] => one
    [4] => two
)
```

The seccond array:

```
Array (
    [0] => first
    [1] => second
)
```

I am looking for a way to grab the values from each array, and make an array like so:

```
Array (
    [one] => first
    [two] => second
)
```

So the value from the first array becomes the key and the value from the second array is the value in the new array. If this makes any sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `array_combine` function of PHP

```
array_combine($array1,$array2);
```

Here `$array1` is for the keys and `$array2` is values

Comment: Super, thanks thought it might be something simple * face palm *

Comment: I will do it in 6 mins as soon as it will allow me to. Thanks again!